# Post-hoc test for randomization analysis

Tags: r, post-hoc, permutation-test, tukey-hsd-test

I've been experimenting with the `coin` package for doing the randomization equivalents of parametric tests.

I've been trying to do a randomized version of an ANOVA analysis, code seen below:

```
## Create simulated data
a <- rnorm(20,mean = 2.8,sd = 3)
b <- rnorm(20,mean = 3,sd = 3)
c <- rnorm(20,mean = 2.7,sd = 3)
data.test <- data.frame(group = c(
                                rep.int('a',times = length(a)),
                                rep.int('b',times = length(b)),
                                rep.int('c',times = length(c))),
                        value = c(a,b,c))

## ANOVA test
summary(aov(data = data.test,formula = value ~ group))

## Randomization Test
independence_test(value ~ group,data = data.test,
    distribution=approximate(B=10e4),teststat = "quadratic")

# p-values should be equal when using normally distributed data
```

My question is... are there any established methods to run a non-parametric equivalent of a Tukey HSD test when using this type of randomization analysis?

Comment: How do you mean equivalent? Do you mean that it utilizes the studentized range distribution or do you mean that it just corrects for multiple comparisons in some way?

Comment: Equivalent in the sense that it results in the same p-value as a conventional tukey's HSD when applied to normally distributed data.  I'm assuming I have to use something that doesn't use the studentized distribution, as i was under the impression that would only be valid for normally distributed data.  Basically, I would go for anything which addresses the same hypothesis as the Tukey's HSD.